# Google Tag Manager is visible on front end

Tags: php, wordpress

I inserted GTM in my website but it's visible on the front end under the footer area. I tried to do it manually and with a plugin but it's still visible. Searched online and found nothing. I disabled all plugins but still visible.

btw I copied the code as it is from GTM and I didn't change anything. is this normal behavior?

[image]

Comment: This code should not appear. If you have already disabled plug-ins, the tag probably remained in the code when you tried to insert it manually. - Did you check this link? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/google-site-verification-html-showing-at-bottom-of-our-site/

Comment: @edrian-biagii I did but I didn't understand whats "A custom HTML tag should contain this malformed tag.".
here is the code I am using
```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Comment: This google-side-verification code doesn't have anything to do with Google Tag Manager.

Comment: @SimonBreton it only appears when I add the GTM code. If it has nothing to do with GTM then what is that and where it comes from?

Comment: @BassamRadi could it be a custom HTML tag in Google Tag Manager? From GTM you can inject anything, anywhere in your front-end. The issue is not GTM but some tags within GTM.

Comment: @SimonBreton suddenly the code disappears from the front end. I don't know what happens but it's fixed.